# Need to create a toggle component using switch which can be reused

Tags: react-native

I want to create a Toggle component but it should be created in such a way that it can be used in various modules, please let me know how can I do this.

Comment: Please follow the guidelines on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of ways to do so. You can use ready modules like [react native paper](https://reactnativepaper.com/) or [react native switch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-switch) or if you want your own implementation you can use [react native gesture handler](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler) and handle clicks and gestures on your own with a couple of views.